# PGFPlots - how to avoid aliasing when plotting 3d surface on limited domain

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, aliasing

I'm trying to render the following plot so that the shading goes right up to the bounding curve without this jagged aliasing.

[image: an aliased rendering of a surface]

The function is $\frac{x}{y^5 + 1}$ in the domain $\sqrt{x} \le y \le 2$ and $0 \le x \le 4$.

I translated this to PGFPlots as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    unbounded coords=jump,
    clip=false,
    view={-30}{45},
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
    ymin=0, ymax=2.15,
    zmin=0, zmax=0.5,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4}, ytick={1, 2},
    ztick={0.5}, zticklabels={$\frac 1 2$}
]
\addplot3[
    samples=100, samples y=250,
    domain=0:4, domain y=0:2,
    colormap/blackwhite, shader=interp, surf, z buffer=sort
] {y >= sqrt(x) ? x / (y^5 + 1) : inf};
\addplot3[
    samples=100, domain=0:8
](
    {(x < 4) ? x : 8-x},
    {(x < 4) ? sqrt(x) : 2},
    {(x < 4) ? x / (sqrt(x)^5 + 1) : 0}
);
\addplot3[
    samples=100, domain=0:8
](
    {(x < 4) ? x : 8-x},
    {(x < 4) ? sqrt(x) : 2},
    {0}
);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and rendered it with LuaLaTeX.

It takes too long to render when I set `samples` and `samples y` high enough to make the aliasing disappear. What I want to do is something like `samples at` and put a bunch of samples near the edges and fewer in the midst, but `samples at` only allows you to set $x$ samples and not $(x,y)$ samples.

Any ideas? Thanks folks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In order to encourage more users to look at your question, you may want to provide us with a complete MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. An ad hoc thought to increase the number of samples in the critical region is to do a parametric plot where now `x` and `y` are functions that are very flat in this region.

Comment: Thanks for your MWE! I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your MWE!

Now to the real problem. You wish to plot the function only in the domain `y >= sqrt(x)`. This can be achieved by doing a parametric plot. I constructed a functions `ycheat(x,y)`, which, for a fixed `x` returns values in the interval between `sqrt(x)` and `2`, which is the maximal value of `y` in your example. That is, if `y` varies between `0` and `2`, `ycheat` runs only between `sqrt(x)` and `2`. You thus get rid of your filter in `y >= sqrt(x) ? x / (y^5 + 1) : inf` as now simply no "bad" `y` occurs, and solve at the same time the issue with the boundary.

Last but not least let me mention that if you add `samples y=1` to the 1-dimensional plots, this reduces the compilation time drastically.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=12cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={ycheat(\x,\y)=sqrt(\x)+\y*(1-sqrt(\x)/2);}]
\begin{axis}[
    unbounded coords=jump,
    clip=false,
    view={-30}{45},
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=0, xmax=4,
    ymin=0, ymax=2.15,
    zmin=0, zmax=0.5,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
    xtick={1, 2, 3, 4}, ytick={1, 2},
    ztick={0.5}, zticklabels={$\frac{1}{2}$}
]
\addplot3[samples y=1,% <-added
    samples=101, domain=0:4
](
    {(x < 4) ? x : 8-x},
    {(x < 4) ? sqrt(x) : 2},
    {0}
);
\addplot3[opacity=0.7,% <- added just for fun
     samples=101, samples y=25,
     domain=0:4, domain y=0:2,
     colormap/blackwhite, shader=interp, surf, z buffer=sort
 ] ({x},{ycheat(x,y)}, {x / (pow(ycheat(x,y),5) + 1)} );
\addplot3[samples y=1,% <-added
    samples=101, domain=0:4
](
    {(x < 4) ? x : 8-x},
    {(x < 4) ? sqrt(x) : 2},
    {(x < 4) ? x / (sqrt(x)^5 + 1) : 0}
);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Wilco; now I see why MWEs are so important.

Comment: Ah, beautiful! I see you also fixed my typographic layout problems with the $y$ and $\frac 1 2$ $z$-tick by widening the figure.

Comment: @holomenicus I actually did not but will do this now, as well as drawing the curves first to get a more 3d like feel.

Comment: I mean in the `\pgfplotsset{width=12cm...`; by default it is narrower and this causes the labels to overlap the surface; cf the picture in the OP.

Comment: @holomenicus I see. No, the `width=12cm` comes from the pre-MWE era, I simply added something and forgot to replace it by what you have. But if you like it, even better. I now changed the plot order and decreased the opacity of the surface. Whether this is really "better" is a matter of taste. The point of this answer is really only the parametric plot cheat. Quite possible it has been done on this site before, but I do not recall seeing it, yet this does not mean much.